# How can I get the line number of a search result of a document in googlescript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

It's seems like a bit actually, but all I'm doing is having:

```
var search = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody.findText("Bill");
```

which is great because I can get the `.getStartOffset();` and the end offset but I need more than that since for the line which the text bill is on I want to make it for example all bold.

So if a document has:

```
Today on June third: /n
I met Bill - :D. /n
It was awesome. /n
```

The line "I met Bill." has to be all bolded and not just bill.
How would I go about doing this? There is text after and before bill as well to take into consideration.

Edit: The example I just gave is just random and when actually using the script, it's assumed that the script doesn't know what the example is. So all the script knows that it needs to find the line that Bill is on, and then bold that line.

Also take into consideration this is googlescript which is SIMILAR to javascript but missing some of the functions.

Comment: Well in regard to your last statement I'm not a JS junkie but I think we can use many JS features that are not documented as GAS, it's like using C in C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as such,

```
var search = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody.findText("Bill");
var arr = [];
if(!!search) {
   arr = search.toString().split("\n");
   var index = -1;
   for(i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
       if(index == -1) {
          if(arr[i].indexOf("Bill") != -1)
             index = i;
       }
   } 
   if(index != -1) {
      alert("Fount at : " + (index+1));
   }
   else {
      alert("Not found");
   }
}
```

Give this a try.

Comment: Trying it out, but I'm a bit confused on what it actually means or what it's doing. I get the if search succeeded get the search result and convert it into a string to separate any different lines but then your using the exact phrase "I met Bill" which I can't use. Like all I know is that the line will contain Bill but I don't know what else the line has , and whatever else it has has to be bolded.

Comment: Apps script is a full javascript language, its not "missing" any functions. Maybe you are confusing it with the DOM api that runs on the browser. That is not js.